# Golang: readsym out of sync

Tags: go, resize, codio

When I run my GoLang program it throws me this exception:

`packages/go-lang/1.3/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l: readsym out of sync`

Does it come from my **amd64** which would not be supported by the module of resize ?

Code block:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/nfnt/resize"
    "image/jpeg"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    //Open
    fmt.Printf("Open data2\n")
    file, err := os.Open("data2.png")
    check(err)

    // decode jpeg into image.Image
    fmt.Printf("Decode file\n")
    img, err := jpeg.Decode(file)
    check(err)
    file.Close()

    // resize to width 1000 using Lanczos resampling
    // and preserve aspect ratio
    resize.Resize(1000, 0, img, resize.Lanczos3)
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
}
```

My os:

```
Linux chamber-tommy 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 
UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After removing the line `resize.Resize(1000, 0, img, resize.Lanczos3)` and its import as well as the variable img. it runs well.

However when I do a `go test` and `go build` in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/nfnt/resize` it works
My prompt:

`PASS ok      github.com/nfnt/resize  0.029s`

An other information is that i get the same error message with a older checkin, for instance 
with: 
`git checkout 8aee0d995b6`

Comment: Context: https://github.com/jnwhiteh/golang/blob/master/src/liblink/objfile.c#L519-L520. On what OS are you? (what does `uname -a` returns?)

Comment: Uname -a returns me:

 `Linux chamber-tommy 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Then resize should work. I didn't see it was incompatible with amd64. Did you try a `go get github.com/nfnt/resize` first? (before compiling your project)

Comment: Yes i did it before to execute my prog `go run main.go`

Comment: Instead of `go run main.go`, could you just do a `go build`?

Comment: same message with `go build`

Comment: If you remove the resize package and line, would that compile?

Comment: Yes it compiles and run. Here is my prompt:
   `$ go run main.go`                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   `Open data2`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   `Decode file`

Comment: There seems to have been quite a lot of changes in the codebase of that project recently (see https://github.com/nfnt/resize/issues/17). It would be interesting to go to your $GOPATH/src/github.com/nfnt/resize, do a `git checkout 8aee0d995b6`, `go build`, `go install`, jsut to see if an *older* version of that plugin works better.

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Does a `go test` executed within `$GOPATH/src/github.com/nfnt/resize` work? Or even a simple `go build`? (again in `resize`)

Comment: Yes it works.
My prompt

`PASS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ok      github.com/nfnt/resize  0.029s     
`

So either the `go test` of this package do not cover this case or it's related to a setting of my host.. no idea yet

Comment: Strange: it compiles, it links, it passes the tests... Can you modify on of the test file in order to add your code (from your main.go) directly in that `$GOPATH/src/github.com/nfnt/resize` test file? Just to see if that would compile that way?

Comment: @JulienHayotte your code works for me, BTW note that you are JPEG deocding a png image. same ubuntu x64 version, Go 1.3.1. Which version of Go are you using?

Comment: Thx guys for your help! I installed it on my desktop and now it works!!
In a first step I was doing my development on CODIO.COM and it seems that it has some limitation... I will warn them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This development was done on a virtual machine on CODIO.COM and the package `"image"` needs some privileges not granted by the host.

Using the same code on my own desktop works.

I created a ticket by codio and we will see what comes out
https://github.com/codio/boxparts/issues/191

Comment: Interesting. Mentioning the exact execution environment in your question might have helped...